# Cannot access propertyResources list from XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, properties

I want to access the "Resources" property of my WPF Project from a XAML file inside the same project.

- I added a Resource "Text123" and set the Access Modifier to "Public",
- I declared the namespace in my XAML file as
  `xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"`
- I added a link to the property from a button content as 
  `Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Text123}"`

As a result I get an error message from Visual Studio saying: **The name "Resources" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties".**

What can I do to get rid of this error?

The `Resources.resx` file is existing in the project and seems to be fine. Even in the `Resources.Designer.vb` file I can see my declared Resource as a `Public ReadyOnly Property`.

P.S: The generated Resources.Designed.vb is:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System

Namespace My.Resources

    'This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    'class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
    'To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
    'with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
    '''<summary>
    '''  A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    '''</summary>
    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0"),  _
     Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(),  _
     Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute()>  _
    Public Module Resources

        Private resourceMan As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager

        Private resourceCulture As Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo

        '''<summary>
        '''  Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        '''</summary>
        <Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>  _
        Public ReadOnly Property ResourceManager() As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager
            Get
                If Object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, Nothing) Then
                    Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyProject.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                    resourceMan = temp
                End If
                Return resourceMan
            End Get
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        '''  Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        '''  resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        '''</summary>
        <Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>  _
        Public Property Culture() As Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo
            Get
                Return resourceCulture
            End Get
            Set
                resourceCulture = value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        '''  Looks up a localized string similar to Cancel.
        '''</summary>
        Public ReadOnly Property Text123() As String
            Get
                Return ResourceManager.GetString("Text123", resourceCulture)
            End Get
        End Property

    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: Does your project build and run?

Comment: The error aborts the build process

Comment: Are you sure that the name of the generated class is "Resource" and not "Resources"?

Comment: This is a typo in my question, sorry. Of course it is "Recources". I corrected the question text. The error remains though

Comment: And what's the namespace and name of the class?

Comment: The Resources class? It is in `Namespace My.Resources` and it is a `Public Module Resources`

Answer (score 0):

Add the default namespace to the namespace declaration, i.e. if your default namespace is "WpfApp1" and the `Resources` module is in the `My.Resources` namespace it should be:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.My.Resources"
```

Comment: I did as you suggested. Now the error message is "The member "Text123" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: When you build? Please post the generated class.

Comment: I added it in my original post.

Comment: It works fine for me to create a new .resx file called "Resource1.resx" in the My folder. Are you getting any other build errors?

Comment: Beside the error before, I get a warning "BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'My.Resources' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace ior the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases"

Comment: Is it maybe because The Resources.resx file is set as "Build Action = Embedded Resource"? Do I need to embedd it somehow in my code beside declaring it in the XAML header?

Comment: No. Try to add a new .resx file with a different name and modify the markup accordingly. If you can't get it to work, you will have to upload your project somewhere if you need any further help.